# Constructor error message

Tags: smart-contract, compilation, constructor

I am writing a smart contract for use within the EOSIO system contract. I am receiving this error message multiple times:

constructor for 'eosio::multi_index<13510798882111488, BP>::item' must explicitly initialize the base class 'BP' which does not have a default constructor

I have checked my constructors and they are all correct - is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have written several constructors for your `BP` class, but do you have a default constructor?

All classes that are to be used as `multi_index` arrays require that the class has a default constructor, even if it is blank.

The default constructor for `BP` would look like:

```
class BP
{
// Your stuff here

public:
  BP(){/* Your default constructor here */}
};
```